# How to add more data into Pdf file created via iText in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am working on a project to create Pdf files from edit text fields in android. I had researched a lot from the internet on how to do this, found mainly two libraries iText and Apwlibrary to do this, but I couldn't find any reliable code which does this without error, nor any tutorial which covered all the areas which need attention for this to work. Somehow I combined a little from everything and my very limited knowledge of android in order to make a basic pdf file, but now I am stuck and I dont know how to add more data into the pdf file. This is the code I came up with in the end.

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException{

   File pdfFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
           Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"pdfdemo");
   if(!pdfFolder.exists()){
       pdfFolder.mkdir();
       Log.d("SelfNoteFragment"," Pdf Created");
   }

   Date date = new Date();
   String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);
   File myFile= new File(pdfFolder+timeStamp+".pdf");
   OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(myFile);

   PdfDocument pdfDocument= new PdfDocument();
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

   getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
   int height=displayMetrics.heightPixels,
           width=displayMetrics.widthPixels;
   PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo= new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(width,height,4).create();
   PdfDocument.Page page=pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
   mRootView.draw(page.getCanvas());
   pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
   try{
       pdfDocument.writeTo(outputStream);

   }catch (IOException e){

   }
```

}

I am a rookie, so if the question doesnt contain relevant points or if the question is vague, plaese specify in the comments below.I have wen through the android documentation regarding the code, but due to my limited knowledge I couldnt figure out what to do.I am trying to be as specific as possible, but if the question still sounds vague, please specify the points needed and I will be more specific. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Class CreatePDF.

```
public class CreatePDF {


private static String FILE = "/xyz";
private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font small = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8,
        Font.ITALIC);

public static final String IMG1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz/logo.png";





Context context;
String payMode;
String ChecqueNo;
String chequeDate;
String BankName;
String BalAmount,planName;
String Duration;
String StartDate,EndDate,PaidAmount;


String name,recieptNo, receiptDate, memberNo, mobileNo, payamount;



String[] DATA,RecieptData,MemberDATA,plandata;


public CreatePDF(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void createPDF(String ReceipData,String MemberData,String PayModdata,String PlanData,String bal)
{


    plandata = PlanData.split(",");
    planName=plandata[0];
    Duration=plandata[1];
    StartDate=plandata[2];
    EndDate=plandata[3];
    PaidAmount=plandata[4];


    MemberDATA = MemberData.split(",");
    name=MemberDATA[0];
    memberNo=MemberDATA[1];
    mobileNo=MemberDATA[2];
    payamount=MemberDATA[3];

    DATA = PayModdata.split(",");
    payMode=DATA[0];
    ChecqueNo=DATA[1];
    chequeDate=DATA[2];
    BankName=DATA[3];
    BalAmount=bal;

    RecieptData = ReceipData.split(",");
    recieptNo=RecieptData[0];
    receiptDate=RecieptData[1];



    Document doc = new Document();


    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);


        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        File file = new File(dir, name+"_"+recieptNo+".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
    }  finally
    {
        doc.close();
    }

}


private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("Payment Report");
    document.addSubject("Using iText");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("author");
    document.addCreator("author");
}


private  void addTitlePage(Document document)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    // We add one empty line
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Lets write a big header






    Paragraph p=new Paragraph("Payment  Receipt", catFont);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    preface.add(p);


    PdfPTable table55 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table55.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table55.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});
    Image i=Image.getInstance(IMG1);
    i.scalePercent(50f);
    table55.addCell(createImageCell(i));
    table55.addCell(createTextCell("abc \n abc"));
    document.add(table55);
    Paragraph p1=new Paragraph(
            "Report generated At: , " + new Date(),
            smallBold);
    p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    preface.add(p1);
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    document.add(preface);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.addCell(getCell("Receipt No: "+recieptNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table.addCell(getCell("Receipt Date: "+receiptDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));


    document.add(table);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table1.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table1.addCell(getCell("Member No: "+memberNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    document.add(table1);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


    PdfPTable table11 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table11.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table11.addCell(getCell("Mobile No: "+mobileNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    document.add(table11);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(5);
    table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Pay Mode: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Cheque No: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Cheque Date: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Amount ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Bank Name:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table2);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    PdfPTable table2Copy = new PdfPTable(5);
    table2Copy.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(payMode, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(ChecqueNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(chequeDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell("Rs. :"+payamount+" INR", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(BankName, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table2Copy);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table3 = new PdfPTable(4);
    table3.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Plan Name: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Duration: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    //table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Paid Amount ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Start Date:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("End Date:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table3);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    PdfPTable table3Copy = new PdfPTable(4);
    table3Copy.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(planName, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(Duration, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
   // table3Copy.addCell(getCell(PaidAmount, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(StartDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(EndDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));

    document.add(table3Copy);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);







    Paragraph Para=new Paragraph(
            "Balance Amount : Rs. "+BalAmount+" INR", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            smallBold);
    Para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(Para);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());


    Paragraph ParaTsys=new Paragraph(
            "name", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            small);
    ParaTsys.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(ParaTsys);

}

public PdfPCell getCell(String text, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}

public PdfPCell getBoldCell(String text, int alignment) {
    Phrase f= new Phrase(text);
    f.setFont(subFont);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(f);
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}
public static PdfPCell createImageCell(String path,int align) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Image img = Image.getInstance(path);
    img.scaleAbsolute(100f, 100f);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(500f, 650f);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
    return cell;
}
private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
}








public static PdfPCell createImageCell(Image img) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}


public static PdfPCell createTextCell(String text) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    cell.addElement(p);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
} }
```

And Call method like this

```
 CreatePDF createPDFf= new CreatePDF(PaymentActivity.this);   
createPDFf.createPDF(ReceiptData,MemberData,PayModeData,PlanData,String.valueOf(Bal));
```

Please ignore the spelling mistakes in code.

And Output look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void LatterPadPdf() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yyyy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String months;
        if (mm > 8) {
            mm = mm + 1;
            months = String.valueOf(mm);
        } else {
            mm = mm + 1;
            months = "0" + String.valueOf(mm);
        }
        int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        fileNameFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        filename = "QUOT_" + (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("LOGIN_USERNAME", null)) + "_" +
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("Customer_short_code", "") + "_" + fileNameFormat;

        filename = filename + ".pdf";
        latterpadfilename = filename;
        String currentDate = new StringBuilder().append(dd).append("/").append(months).append("/").append(yyyy).toString();
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "External Storage not available or you don't have permission to write");
        } else {

            File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("pdf_path", null));
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                pdfFile_latter = new File(myFile, filename);

            } else {
                myFile = new File("/sdcard" + PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("pdf_path", null));
                myFile.mkdirs();
                pdfFile_latter = new File(myFile, filename);

            }


            //  pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
        }


        Document document = new Document();

        try {

            PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile_latter));
            docWriter.setPageEvent(new PDFBackground());
            document.open();

            addEmptyLine(document, 3);

            document.add(tableGoldUsername("Date : " + currentDate));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tablemethod_MR("To, ", "MR : " + rSharedpreference.getString("EmpName", "")));

//-----------------------------------------------
            document.add(tableGoldUsername(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("name_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("address_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("city_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("state_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("pin_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("mobile_new", ""))));
            document.add(tablemethod_new(CheckValues(rSharedpreference.getString("email_new", ""))));

            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tableHeader(" QUOTATION "));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            // document.add(tableDaimondRate());
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Shall be as per the market price at the time of delivery."));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Labour Charges :- ", "All items shall be @ " + rSharedpreference.getString("gram_rate", "") +
                    " xxxxxxxx @ " + rSharedpreference.getString("min_rate", "")));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tableHeader(" TERMS AND CONDITIONS "));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Delivery :- ", "Within 35 to 40 working days from the date of final approved order."));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Payment :-", "xxxxxx"));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Damaged :-", "xxxxxx"));
            // document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Return Policy :-", "We have no return policy applicable in the generic products or multiple orders placed in the same category"));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Supporting Documents :-", "xxxxxxx."));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("Size :-", "xxxxxx"));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tableGoldParaNote("", " xxxxx"));
            addEmptyLine(document, 1);
            document.add(tableGoldParaNote("Note :-", "xxxxx "));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("DISCLAIMER :-", "xxxxxx"));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("", "xxxx"));
            document.add(tableGoldParagraph("", "xxxx"));


            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Prefer given Reference.
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

Comment: This was very Helpful.. @Ramachandra Singh